# TSQL: How to get a UNION result from two tables with XML information in T1.Field_A and nvarchar in T2.Field_A

Tags: xml, t-sql, union, multiple-tables

I have two separate data input tables from different sources (one direct insert, one via API). I´m trying to fetch a unified list of tuples out of these two tables using the UNION command. Unfortunately the information of the field SourceEventID has different source types:

In table1, the information for SourceEventID is stored inside an xml in the field IncidentRequest_XML (type=xml).
In table2 the data for this field is stored as a string (type = nvarchar).

My questions are:

> Is it possible to get the result by using the union command in a different way and if not, how is it possible to get the unified list out of the two tables with the told circumstances?

Thanks a lot!

I tried to get the result using the UNION command but it told me, the following:

> The data type xml cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable.

```
SELECT
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY A.SourceSystem ORDER BY Date) as Row,
    IncidentRequest_XML.query('INCIDENT_REQUEST/SourceEventID') as SourceEventID,
    'FOO' as Type
FROM dbo.Source_A 
INNER JOIN dbo.ConfigTable C ON A.SourceSystem = C.SourceSystem
WHERE C.ReturnStatus = 1
UNION
SELECT
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY B.SourceSystem ORDER BY Date) as Row,
    SourceEventID,
    'BAR' as Type
FROM dbo.Source_B
INNER JOIN dbo.ConfigTable C ON B.SourceSystem = C.SourceSystem
WHERE C.ReturnStatus = 1
```

What I expect is the following result:

```
ROW     SourceEventID                              Type
1       <SourceEventID>abc12345</SourceEventID>    FOO
2       testcall123                                BAR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your *expected result* you see, that XML and string would be mixed in the same column. This is not possible...

What you can do, is either use `.value()` instead of `.query()` to read the SourceEventId as string:

```
IncidentRequest_XML.value('(INCIDENT_REQUEST/SourceEventID/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')  as SourceEventID
```

Or you can use a cast, to transform your result of `.query()` to a string:

```
CAST(IncidentRequest_XML.query('INCIDENT_REQUEST/SourceEventID') AS NVARCHAR(100)) as SourceEventID
```

Good to know: `.query()` returns a XML-typed result, which is the result of a XQuery-expression. On the other hand `.value()` can deal with a singleton value only (therefore we need the `(blah)[1]` and the specific type.

Comment: Hi Shnugo, thank you for the fast support. Your answer solved my problem.